# How should I join these two tables?

Tags: sql-server

These are two tables I have.

```
 | StockId | Item1 | Quantity1|
     1        10        5
     1        11        6

 | StockId | Item2 | Quantity2 |
     1        12        4
```

I need to join these two tables so that I get the output:

```
 | StockId | Item1 | Quantity1 | Item2 | Quantity2 |
      1       10        5          12       4
      1       11        6          -        -
```

Each table may contain 1 or more rows. I have tried joining tables but that wouldn’t work.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.StockId = Table2.StockId
```

This would give me the output:

```
 | StockId | Item1 | Quantity1 | Item2 | Quantity2 |
      1       10        5          12       4
      1       11        6          12       4
```

Answer (score 2):

@JamesZ your query will fail in below scenario.. you are generating RN based on Item1 and Item2 and not considering StockId also while joining two tables you are not considering StockIds.
In below example I have added more rows just to make sure query gives correct result.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (StockId INT ,Item1 INT,Quantity1 INT)
CREATE TABLE #T2 (StockId INT ,Item2 INT,Quantity2 INT)

INSERT INTO #T1
SELECT 1,10,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,11,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,9 ,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,8 ,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,10,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,11,6

INSERT INTO #T2
SELECT 1,12,4 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,12,4

;WITH T1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockId ORDER BY Item1) AS RN, * 
    FROM #T1
) 
,T2
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StockId ORDER BY Item2) AS RN, * 
    FROM #T2
)
SELECT T1.StockId,T1.Item1,T1.Quantity1,T2.StockId,T2.Item2,T2.Quantity2
FROM T1 
FULL JOIN T2 ON T1.StockId = T2.StockId AND T1.RN = T2.RN
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database looks like it needs re-thinking, because your requirement isn't that clear, but you can do it with something like this:

```
select * 
from 
(select row_number() over (order by Item1) as RN, * from Table1) T1
full outer join
(select row_number() over (order by Item2) as RN, * from Table2) T2
on T1.RN = T2.RN
```